# Question has comment but comment is not showing

Tags: bug, status-completed, automatic-comments

I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056090/redirect-in-htaccess-to-force-uppercase-url) for closure earlier as being a duplicate. This normally automatically creates an appropriate comment.

I see the usual "show 1 more comment" link below the question:

> [image: show 1 more comment link]

But clicking this link does not show any comments and the link disappears.

> [image: no comments]

Refreshing the page makes the "show 1 more comment" link return, but no comments are displayed. There really should be at least 1 comment on this question (my "automatic comment" that relates to the close reason) and the system thinks there is, yet it's not displayed. (?)

**EDIT:** The suggested duplicate (to this question) would imply that a mod has deleted my "automatic comment" that relates to the close reason - although that wouldn't really make sense (or was a mistake).

Comment: @Ivar Well, kind of, except there really should be a comment on this question, unless a mod has deleted my "automatic comment" that relates to the close reason - which wouldn't make sense (or was a mistake).

Comment: I don't think this is the same problem. It's a duplicate suggested auto comment that was deleted by Community... but I'm not sure why it was deleted since it wasn't flagged and the question didn't get closed.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a bug - according to the network tab in my browser, when you click on "show 1 more comment"...[you get nothing back](https://i.imgur.com/grYzzy3.png). It's an empty response. EDIT: Oh, and [here are the headers](https://i.imgur.com/VT9oxB4.png)

Comment: That "1 more comment" issue is not new: [The system sees a comment that doesn't exist](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44249)

Comment: ... yes, it would seem. However, that leads onto a secondary question: Why was the comment deleted in the first place? (See @Catija's comment above).

Comment: Trying to reason about functionality that is open for race conditions by design is futile. The proposed dupe answer is the best  you can hope for.

Comment: The comment was removed because the user disagreed that the duplicate you proposed answered their question and the system now removes them in that case. ...  That deletion is going direct to the database which leaves the result you see. We'll look into sending the deletion through the standard comment deletion routes, which will keep the comment count correct.

Comment: @Catija Ok, thanks - maybe you can put that as an answer so I can accept it (and reference the question explaining why the "show X more comments" was showing to begin with).

Comment: Ah, it's just been closed...!

Comment: If @Catija is correct then the duplicate isn't really the same situation, is it?

Comment: @Catija I'm sorry, *what*? The user disagreeing that the question is a duplicate **removes the comment**? How does that make any sense? It doesn't remove the vote. And either way, the disagreement of  a single party doesn't invalidate my opinion that the question is a duplicate.

Comment: @CodyGray: it *kind of* does, because the comment is now a question: *Does this post answer your question?*, and they disagreed. The duplicate vote still stands and the [review queue still sees the suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/25266438), so why keep the comment? There is no comment for other close reasons..

Comment: @CodyGray: To me, it makes perfect sense to remove the comment here. It is addressed to the OP, and the OP has seen it and responded. We may not agree with their response to the comment, but that doesn't make it obsolete.

Comment: This makes some amount of sense. Anyone else closing the question can already see the proposed duplicate via the CV menu, so the comment would be kinda pointless in that instance. Same reason that the comment gets deleted when the question actually gets closed.

Comment: @Magisch "Anyone else closing the question can already see the proposed duplicate via the CV menu" - By "CV menu", you are referring to the _review queue_? I suppose the problem I have with this is that anyone viewing the question itself (including the person who flagged the question as a dupe to begin with) can no longer see the suggested dupe. I spent time looking for that dupe and now it's "gone". It would be helpful to get feedback from the OP as to _why_ the dupe did not answer the question, which we often got in the past - in the form of a comment - when the comment was still present.

Comment: @MrWhite No not the review queue, when a user clicks the *"close"* button on a post they'll still see a badge by the duplicate option, and when clicked it will still show the suggested duplicate, even if the comment is removed

Comment: @NickA Ah, unfortunately, as the person who actually cast the close vote I don't see the suggested duplicate! I can only see that I cast a "duplicate close vote" and the only option is to "Retract Close Vote". I should be able to see the "suggested duplicate" as well (I shouldn't have to search my browser history).

Comment: @MartijnPieters "This makes some amount of sense..." How about when we've edited that auto-comment so that it's *not* a question. Is it then removed? That would not makes sense. When I edit that comment it's because I'm adding important information...

Comment: @CindyMeister: I imagine it is going to be treated the same way as when the post is closed as a duplicate: the comment deleted, as is any other that matches a pattern.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: The duplicate comment is no longer automatically deleted when the post owner rejects a duplicate post suggestion. Thanks for your feedback.

<strike>The behavior or deleting the suggested duplicate comment when the post owner rejects the suggestion is intentional and was added last week (at the same time as [fixing a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343216/51) where sometimes the post owner duplicate rejection did not work).</strike>

The reason for this is that the main purpose of the comment is to inform the poster (both through an inbox message and through the comment) of a potential duplicate. If the post owner rejects this suggestion, there is no more reason to keep the comment around. (The comment is not deleted if it was edited). The comment is not there to inform other users about the potential duplicate. Note: owner rejection does not reject the duplicate flag. This stays in place for other reviewers to evaluate.

In any event, the bug here was not in the comment being deleted, rather in the `Post.CommentCount` field (which is used for creating that link) not being updated in the case of the comment being deleted through post owner duplicate rejection. This has been fixed.

Comment: *"The reason for this is that the main purpose of the comment is to inform the poster (both through an inbox message and through the comment) of a potential duplicate."* That is incorrect. What you describe is the purpose of the blue notification banner that appears at the top of questions which have been flagged as a possible duplicate. That banner's purpose is to alert the asker of the question, and that banner should indeed disappear if the asker indicates their disagreement. However, the purpose of the comment is to alert *other viewers* of the question that there is a related question.

Comment: There's an additional issue: a reasonable amount of duplicate flags end up ageing away despite being "true" (because it takes 3 people with the right technical knowledge to end up seeing them). In that case the comment remains useful.

Comment: @Yaakov in my question [Do not remove “Does this answer your question?” comments when the OP says “No”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393630/do-not-remove-does-this-answer-your-question-comments-when-the-op-says-no) this change is discussed. A comment indicating that someone thought that a question was a duplicate, helps a lot more people than just the OP. Could you take a look there, if you haven't already?

Comment: Yeah, hearing the feedback. Will consider