# Do not remove "Does this answer your question?" comments when the OP says "No"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

[Catija wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393581/question-has-comment-but-comment-is-not-showing#comment753279_393581):

> The ["Does this answer your question? [Link to possible duplicate]"] comment was removed because the user disagreed that the duplicate you proposed answered their question **and the system now removes them in that case**. ... That deletion is going direct to the database which leaves the result you see.

Ok, but:

- A question asker generally doesn't recognize that a duplicate actually answers their question; after all, they're the one asking the question, meaning they don't know a solution to their problem, and perhaps they don't recognize one when someone shows it to them, because it's in a form they don't expect.
- When the question is not closed as a duplicate, the comment is useful for later visitors wanting to perhaps actually try and see whether the duplicate answers *their* question, or wanting to help explain the OP why the duplicate actually answers their question.
- This deletion breaks the "Linked" section in the sidebar, which used to link to possible duplicates - but now that the comment is hard-deleted, the link is gone as well. See [redirect in htaccess to force uppercase URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056090/redirect-in-htaccess-to-force-uppercase-url) which has 2 duplicate votes but no comments and no "Linked" section in the sidebar.
- The close-voter [can't see anymore which question they suggested as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393581/question-has-comment-but-comment-is-not-showing#comment753604_393581):

  > as the person who actually cast the close vote I don't see the suggested duplicate! I can only see that I cast a "duplicate close vote" and the only option is to "Retract Close Vote". I should be able to see the "suggested duplicate" as well

In short: the "possible duplicate" or "Does this answer your question?" comment is for **more people than just the OP** and serves a bigger purpose than just asking the OP a question, namely linking to the other question for **all other users**, and **should not be automatically removed**, especially not if it only takes one click from the OP to do so, because the OP is not in the position to determine that.

I may just sound angry because [you're breaking my workflow](https://xkcd.com/1172/), but you're carving away at the duplicate system here, without any announcement of this change - as far as I could find.

Comment: Not sure if relevant but this feature has been in place since last week

Comment: @Nick if I'd found out about this earlier, I'd have complained earlier. I practically only dupe-hammer using my gold badges, so I don't encounter this situation too often.

Comment: Not saying you wouldn't have :), just a bit of information, as I personally hadn't noticed it previously either. I had to ask to find out when it was implemented

Comment: I wonder if this happens if you actually type the comment, but don't vote to close (I often do this, when I'm pretty confident it is, but giving the OP the benefit of doubt and I don't want to "gold badge" it).

Comment: @Larnu I also wonder if it happens when edited, as I edit mine to *"Possible duplicate of"* so I don't get replies from OP

Comment: @Larnu AFAIK, it's a dumb string match that checks whether any comment contains a link to the suggested duplicate, or something like that. See also [Do not automatically remove hand-written comments when closing as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate). This feature has been problematic for years, as the edit count was also ignored (which was meant to let such comments remain, when the poster edited them).

Comment: Wow, this seems to make about *zero* sense whatsoever. Am I right to assume that the next step in this feature development process is auto-validating the "abusive" flags askers sometimes slap on these duplicate suggestion comments?

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I complained to Catija about this yesterday. Seems this was a regression introduced during the massive rework to post notices. I firmly believe it’s a bug, but there’s an indication that staff intended to remove it. Either way, it was a mistake and needs to come back. The comment also needs to get rephrased so it isn’t asking a question.

Comment: If nothing else, in the case where it's actually _not_ a duplicate, the comment can also prevent other people from suggesting the same question as a duplicate.

Comment: *"The close-voter I can't see anymore which question they suggested as duplicate"* This is actually really important in my view. Especially if I want to cite said duplicate to explain why it's a duplicate. It's also improtant to the OP, as they can cite the duplicate in their question and explain why it's not a dupe. If both the OP and the voter can't *easily* determine the dupe candidate after they've said "no" this *could* also more easily enable "pile on" votes from those with the Close Vote priviledge.

Comment: The duplicate comment deletion [has been reversed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393819/51). Thanks everyone for your feedback.

Comment: @CodeCaster I can confirm that it the deletion is not using a "dumb string match". Also, when these comments are deleted (for instance, when the post is actually closed as a duplicate) the edit count is not being ignored.

Comment: @Yaakov thanks! Maybe not anymore, but [it used to be like that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. The duplicate comment is no longer being deleted when the post owner rejects a duplicate post suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for both fixing it and giving feedback!

Answer (score 14):

> When the question is not closed as a duplicate, the comment is useful for later visitors wanting to perhaps actually try and see whether the duplicate answers their question, or wanting to help explain the OP why the duplicate actually answers their question.

Also, removing the OP's answer doesn't help the OP, if someone says "no this doesn't answer my question because ...", this is also important to know and talk about. By removing the comment, people don't know if the OP's answer is NO, or if the comment was removed for some other reason. I will be more concentrated if I see the OP's answer in comment more than just see nothing. I will probably just see the suggested duplicate and agree 95% of time without caring about the OP. And so if the question gets closed, the OP will end  up angry.

To be clear, this just adds confusion for everyone. Doesn't help anyone. Let the comment in place even if OP disagrees. Actually, seems the user just hit a button "NO" that would be better to generate an auto no answer for the OP, or ask to the OP a custom reason for why they disagree. This would be much better than deleting something useful (we all know comments are temporary but temporary != useless, a question's critical life is generally 1 day, comments are useful for this period of time).

---

Note: Martijn said:

> This is consistent with other close votes.

Duplicate are not like other close reason, duplicate actually should not be call "close a question" but "redirect a question". That why it's special. Duplicate are generally good to have, all other closed question are DELETED at some point not duplicate.

Answer (score 11):

Please do not delete useful comments. When I flag a comment that suggests a fix, which OP tries and confirms it doesn't work, my flag is rejected. Why should a comment be deleted automatically by the system when OP declines it?

Quoting Cody Gray:

> What you describe is the purpose of the blue notification banner that appears at the top of questions which have been flagged as a possible duplicate. That banner's purpose is to alert the asker of the question, and that banner should indeed disappear if the asker indicates their disagreement. However, the purpose of the comment is to alert other viewers of the question that there is a related question.

The comment is not for the OP! The comment is for others to see what has been suggested. We are not asking OP to tell us if our judgement is right, we are telling them that this questions has been answered before, or the exact same question has been asked already. The text of the comment is not suitable, and many of us would edit it to say: "Possible Duplicate: ...". (A better text IMO would be  "*This has been answered here:* ") We do not want OP to tell us that this is not the right duplicate target; we want them to try the suggestions from that post and update the question if these suggestions were not helpful.

We close questions as duplicates, not because someone had the exact same problem, but because the exact answer has been written before. In other words, when we suggest a duplicate we say that **this is our answer to this question.** It's ok if the OP replies to us that it didn't help them, but **do not delete our answers!**

Answer (score -28):

I really don't see this as an issue. The comment, as worded, is *aimed at the OP*. The OP has responded to it, it's purpose is done. The comment is *also* deleted if the OP accepts the duplicate, or the post is closed as a duplicate when sufficient additional close votes are cast. Comments are ephemeral, deleting it here absolutely makes sense.

That the comment was also being used *by others for other purposes* can be addressed in other ways.

First, the dupe vote is *not gone*, it is there for other close-voters to see (`close (n)` on the post, voting to close as duplicate suggests the target post as the first choice, the close review queue shows the duplicate post as a tab). *This is consistent with other close votes.*

Only those that voted to close the post as a duplicate can't currently see what the voted to close the post as a duplicate of, so at most 2 people are inconvenienced by this. This can be remedied by recording the duplicate target somewhere else. *Personally, I'd rather see the duplicate target being included in the post timeline.*

Finally, duplicate voters sometimes get it wrong. I don't see a need to record such errors in the related posts sidebar. We can always add a new comment stating the posts are related if not an outright duplicate.

Comment: "We can always add a new comment stating the posts are related if not an outright duplicate." Which will be deleted, since "Comments are ephemeral". Also, the wording of the comment is immaterial to its deletion; it gets deleted even if you edit it to remove the question, as indicated in the comments.

Comment: The difference between duplicate votes and all other votes is that the former **point to other questions**. The OP should not be the sole responsible person to with the power to remove the only immediately visible link (for many visitors) to the other question. Yes, wrong duplicates are suggested, but correct duplicates are negated by OPs as well. And yes, the automatically posted comment talks to the OP, but it has not done so in like 13 years, that's a [recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339563/confusing-comment-does-this-answer-your-question).

Comment: What I mean is that a lingering "possible duplicate of" comment, automatically posted years ago where the OP has visibly disagreed, has helped me more often than not when researching actual problems encountered in my work as a developer. These comments are **not just for the OP**, despite the recent change of phrasing.

Comment: @CodeCaster: the new phrasing makes it squarely about the OP. That there maybe are other uses may just have been overlooked, but I find those comments to be clutter. We should instead look for better ways of capturing those other use cases.

Comment: I, and I am not alone, seriously doubt whether there are any good intentions at play, because the intentions are not advertised. Yeah, (new) users don't like comments under their question implying that they didn't search well enough. But there's a chance they didn't. That's life. People don't dupe-vote to insult question askers, they do so to _help_ them. The solution is not to let those users delete such comments with one button click.

Comment: @CodeCaster: there have been loads of other changes and developments rolled out, not every single tweak needs pre-announcing. That's going to be hugely prohibitive, and you cannot predict how every change is going to be received.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I completely get it that there is a lot of trust lost between community and the company, but we *really* don't need to see every small change we don't like in a light of 'deliberate action to undermine the community'.

Comment: @CodeCaster: and again, **the dupe vote is not lost**. The comment is one small component in giving the OP a chance to confirm that the linked duplicate helps them. They don't have to accept that it does, they frequently get it wrong, they sometimes act with hostility towards someone suggesting a dupe, but deleting the comment is not an act of trying to bury anything. Keeping the comment around is not going to make anything friendlier or more hostile.

Comment: I agree with your latest comment, but have a hard time explaining what I do mean.

Comment: I think part of the problem here is that the wording of the comment was changed.
People still hold on to the old intent / meaning of the comment as a temporary signpost, not necessarily targeted at the OP.

Comment: "I really don't see this as an issue. The comment, as worded, is aimed at the OP." <= This is the issue, the comment is not only aimed at the OP, the previous notice visible to OP only was that, a comment pointing to a possible duplicate is useful to others visitors as well willing to check the proposed duplicate target.

Comment: @Tensibai: The *old wording* was perhaps aimed wider, but the *current wording is not*. Those *other uses* can be addressed in different ways.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, we have notices visible for author only (on edits, etc), if that's aimed at the OP only, then don't make it a comment at all OR let it be for others to double check whatever the wording is. If it's not intended to anyone else than the OP it should not be a comment at all

Comment: @Tensibai: The current wording is "Does this answer your question? *link*". That's absolutely aimed at the OP. Lets discuss, constructively, what the other use-cases were and *find better ways of addressing those*.

Comment: @Tensibai: sure, perhaps there should not be *any* comments. I'd be fine with that too, as long as the same use-cases are addressed. I think the comment can be a starting point to discuss the possible duplicate if the OP is open to constructive discourse. Which happens more often than not, actually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then if it's a starting point for discussion why allowing a single vote to remove the entry point ? I fail to see the logic, if it's an entry point to discuss the validity, then let someone else rehash how the proposed duplicate may solve the problem after this comment instead of dropping it. And if it's just for OP's sake, they can still ping close voter so a comment is useless. There's just a large incoherence with the actual implementation

Comment: @Tensibai: because the comment is addressed to the OP. They are entitled to their opinion, the question asked of them was answered. They absolutely can be wrong, they often are, but *that doesn't make the comment not obsolete*.

Comment: @Martijn in my opinion, the OP has no authority over when a comment is obsolete. An obvious case is  a comment pointint out an error in a post, and when the error has been fixed, the comment definitely is obsolete and can be removed. In all other cases, it's at least a grey area. If someone asks the OP for clarification, _even_ if it is _"Are you sure you want to do it X way, Y way is way more common"_, **helps later visitors**. The OP can say _"Yeah I wanna do X"_, but any later visitor may not know of Y, and, with the "obsolete" comment now gone, is none the wiser.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's probably where we disagree, now OP doesn't have to answer "No, this is not a correct duplicate because ...", they just click and no-one has a clue if the comment had been edited (or not) to give more clue, its frustrating to walk on eggshell ignoring previous interactions. If another comment repeat what was in the dupe, the Op may take has harassment and it will feed the "SO is unwelcoming" trope. Either make it an OP only notice, or let the comment be until close or aging. This half state has more chances to cause problems than it solve IMHO.

Comment: @Tensibai: They should not respond with a comment *anyway*. They should be editing their post to ensure that it is clear that it isn't a duplicate. There is no need to 'walk on eggshells', responding constructively and keeping your humour isn't that hard. :-)

Comment: @CodeCaster: That's where comments have *always* fallen short. Comments are there to interact with the author of the post, less so with everyone else. If there is something substantial enough to help other visitors, then *consider putting that in an answer*. None of this doesn't make this automated comment any less obsolete.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, with the way things are enforced now, I'm always weighting a lot what I say. Fact is, few people understand that and answer in comment saying "No this is not a duplicate, I ask about X not x, are you dumb enough to not see it ?" in comment and we have to guide them through editing their questions to clarify. This is lost now they can just get rid of the remark and won't have any incentive to even express why they don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Tensibai: "are you dumb enough to not see it" is grounds for flagging, and you'd be perfectly within your right to ignore that post altogether if you get a reception like that. I don't see how removing the duplicate comment is making such a situation *worse*. Why not respond with *I see the duplicate suggestion comment is gone, perhaps you dismissed the suggested duplicate?* and engage them that way?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's what I call worse, I've no idea what has been said before, comments are not for chit chat, repeating the same advice is seen as rude. Why on earth creating more work than existing ? The notice could have been reworded in various way without causing that much trouble but the choice has been made toward this wording and a workflow creating more incertitude than before... I've a hard time understanding why.

Comment: And re: "you'd be perfectly within your right to ignore that post altogether if you get a reception like that" <= Ignoring the problem won't solve its cause, I wouldn't be arguing about why I find this detrimental if ignoring was a correct solution.

Comment: @Tensibai: If someone is being abusive, you are not necessarily going to convince them. Of course responding with a supportive counter helping them see why the duplicate helps is wonderful and absolutely better, but ignoring an abusive user (after flagging the abuse) is always better than engaging in kind. I'm just reminding people that *not engaging with an abusive user* is always an option, because many people seem to forget this. I'm absolutely not advocating ignoring every problem.

Comment: I should have let this too often see example aside as it distract from the point. I've thick skin enough to get over insults when they're caused by a misconception, the problem stand that using a comment for OP only communication is bad and when it start a convo it is often as bad. If the debatable choice is done to addresd the OP, then an OP only notice is what to use, if a comment is used, then it should be written a s an observation and stay until the question is close or the votes age away. Please choose one, but not a muddy middle ground frustrating and likely to spark more hurt

Comment: (plea addressed to the organization, nothing personal Martijn)

Comment: @Tensibai: you are repeating yourself here, several times now. You have already expressed how you feel about this..

Comment: *"Finally, duplicate voters sometimes get it wrong. I don't see a need to record such errors in the related posts sidebar. We can always add a new comment stating the posts are related if not an outright duplicate."* Then have "roomba" clear these up. Close votes age away, so delete the comment then. If the Voter retracts their vote, delete the comment then.

Comment: As an example, I closed (as I have a gold badge) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60038191/2029983). The OP [reposted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60040313/2029983) it and got an answer exactly the same as the previous flagged dup. If I didn't have a gold badge, my comments about that the question was a dup would have been deleted, because the OP effectively wouldn't try to implement the solution they were given for their code and said it "wasn't" a duplicate. The fact that they accepted an answer that is identifical to one in the duplicate question proves otherwise.

Comment: @Larnu: and that still would happen with the comment not deleted. It's not that the comment was deleted that people don't recognize that a duplicate is applicable.

Comment: But had the OP been able to respond "No" and the comment was deleted then the deletion in that scenario is plain wrong. It *was* a duplicate and the comment to suggest so can be upvoted and others can vote the same way more obviously; as they can see the link in the comments, review, and vote